# TRY_PARSE for scientific notation different between servers

Tags: sql-server

I have two instances of SQL Server 11.0.6020.0 (English language) on different machines

I noticed the following behaviour on one of them:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float) -- yields NULL
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(float, '1.0000000000000000E+00') -- yields 1
```

On the other one, however, both queries yield 1.

Can anybody give me a hint on what could be the difference between those systems leading to this behaviour?

Comment: Are you *sure* the logins have the same login? If you add a culture, does it give consistent results?

Comment: For starters, try `SELECT TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float USING 'en-US')`. `TRY_PARSE` defers to .NET for parsing while `TRY_CONVERT` does not, so that's at least one major way for differences to happen.

Comment: Point in case for the latter: `SELECT TRY_PARSE('1D+0' AS FLOAT)` gives `NULL` while `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, '1D+0')` gives `1`, because the latter allows for the non-standard, FORTRAN style exponent that the engine supports but the .NET Framework has no knowledge of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like the you are using different languages for the `LOGIN` you are using on the different servers. `TRY_PARSE`, by default, uses the culture of the `LOGIN` if one isn't specified. If you specify a culture, you will get consistent results regardless of the `LOGIN` language settings.

For example, if you use the below, French returns `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float USING 'en-GB'),
       TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float USING 'fr-FR');
```

And if you use these 2 statements notice, as well, that French returns `NULL` without a culture specified:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE British; --because I live in England, so I don't speak English?
SELECT TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float), --Returns 1;
       TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float USING 'en-GB') --Returns 1
GO
SET LANGUAGE French;
SELECT TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float), --Returns NULL;
       TRY_PARSE('1.0000000000000000E+00' as float USING 'en-GB') --Returns 1
GO
```